# Run certain number of threads/processes simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-2.6

I need to run certain number of threads or processes simultaneously until all of them are completed. How do I do that in Python 2.6. (Note: I believe Python 3.0 has `ThreadPoolExecutor` but that doesn't help me because we are on 2.6).

I tried the following:

```
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)

    try:
        for table_name in table_list:
            pool.apply_async(Processor(table_name, self.type, 
                self.properties).exec())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pool.terminate()
    else:
        pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

but it's processing each table sequentially.  What I want is, if there are 10 tables & Pool size is 5, then it should first start 5 threads.  Once one of them completes it should pick the next one, then next and so on, till all of them are processed.

How can I do this in Python 2.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pool.apply_async(Processor(table_name, self.type, self.properties).exec())
```

Immediately invokes `.exec` you need to delay so instead pass the `.exec` function:

```
pool.apply_async(Processor(table_name, self.type, self.properties).exec)
```

See [`apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback]]])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async)

Comment: Thanks, Dan! That worked.  A different - yet -related question.  Now the output is all mixed up so I can't tell which line came from which process.  Is there an easy way to fix this?  Do I've to use a logging framework or something like that?

Comment: Either have them prefix their output lines or have them write to different outputs.